# due to paragraph marks my label printer gets a margin error?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, macros, label-printer

I installed a label printer [LP2824](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/desktop/lp-2824-plus.html). and now i am trying to print via network.
I installed a macro, in word to print out my selected text.

in word when i press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> i get a paragraphs mark like this
[image: selected-txt]

to print out like this, i get an error

> The margins of section 1 are set outside the printable area of ​​the
>   page. Do you want to continue anyway?

when using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and not selecting the paragraph mark at the end it does work? 
[image: working-selected-txt]

My question is how do i get it to work, by selecting text with the paragraph marks?
(meaning any selected text)

Comment: Does the text print outside the label if you accept that dialog?

Comment: @Adam yes, the label is blank!. But my problem has been fixed, by editing the macro to turn the paragraphs mark into <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>ENTER</kbd> thing-is?

Comment: You should post an answer for what you did to fix it.